# get commerce order variables dpm without loading order again

Tags: 7, theming

I try to get order variables using devel module from inside custom order template page--admin--commerce--orders__%.tpl.php.

I use code `$order = commerce_order_load(123);`

Question: is it possible not to load full order again and get the variables ? (assuming that I am on order page, the variables should be loaded anyways correct?)
Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it.

Loaded entities are cached for at least that request, so you're either loading up an entity which hasn't been loaded yet, in which case the DB load is inevitable, or you're simply retrieving the already-loaded entity from static cache.

As an aside, don't load up entities in template files - always do it in a preprocess hook and pass the variable in.

Comment: you mean something like here https://www.drupal.org/node/2753861#comment-11478081 . In template.php check for entity type (commerce_order) and then define custom template for it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `commerce_order_load` to load the order with all the data. If the order already has been loaded somewhere else on the page, the order won't be loaded twice, but the order will be fetched from static cache instead. So it's fine to load the same order multiple times.

If you do need to clear the cache, (maybe you need to compare the order to what is in the datebase to see what has changed), then you can use use `commerce_order_load_multiple` or call `entity_load` directly.